# Limit of geometric series when common ratio tends to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Whilst working on a problem involving a geometric series today, I stumbled across an interesting result which I've never seen before.

It is well known that the sum of the finite geometric series (for $r \neq 1$) is given by:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

For $r=1$ the formula above breaks down, but the sum of the geometric series in this case is very simple:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 1 = n+1$$

So intuitively I wondered if the following limit might hold:

$$\lim_{r \to 1} \frac{1-r^n}{1-r} = n$$

I tried this out with a few numerical examples on a calculator and it appears to be correct, but it seems quite a surprising result.

Is this a well known result?  Does it have a name?  Does anyone know where I can read more about it?

And most of all, how can it be proven rigorously?

Comment: expanding $1-r^n$ doesn't help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a finite positive integer $n$, we immediately have the factorization $$1-r^n = (1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1}).$$

For real-valued $n$, consider the function $f(x) = x^n$.  The definition of the derivative is $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}.$$  If we can accept that the derivative is $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$, it immediately follows that for $a = 1$, we have $$n = n \cdot 1^{n-1} = f'(1) = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1}.$$

Comment: Yes, but the limit doesn't deal with positive integer n.  It's about real numbers arbitrarily close to 1.

Comment: The factorization furnishes a valid justification for the value of the limit for positive integers $n$.  The limit is with respect to $r$, not $n$.

Comment: Yeah, you're completely right.  Thanks heropup.  This whole thing is very clear now.

Answer (score 0):

When r is not a finite positive integer, we can expand the numerator using the binomial series in powers of $\epsilon = (r-1)$

$\lim_{r \to 1} \frac{1-r^n}{1-r} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{(1+\epsilon)^n-1}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{n\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}n+O(\epsilon)=n$

Answer (score 0):

Using L'Hospital $$\lim_{r \to 1} \Big(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\Big) = \lim_{r \to 1} \Big(\frac{-n~r^{n-1}}{-1}\Big)=\lim_{r \to 1}~ (n~r^{n-1})=n$$